# CakePHP Auth->login not generating query for request data

Tags: authentication, cakephp-2.0, components

I have the Auth component working perfectly for an application running Cake 2.4.1, and I need to copy it to another application that is also running Cake 2.4.1. I copied over everything I could think of that has to do with Auth stuff, but it just does not work in the second application. It refuses to log me in. The call to `$this->Auth->login()` fails even though it gets exactly the same data as the application that works.

Both applications are using exactly the same database and user login.
Both applications get exactly the same request data in the POST request.

First of all, here is my setup.

In AppController.php:

```
public $uses = array ('User');
public $components = array    ( 'Session',
                                'CPRACL.CPRACL' => array (),
                                'Auth' => array (
//                                        'loginAction' => array ('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'login'),
//                                        'logoutRedirect' => '/users/login',
//                                        'loginRedirect' => '/',
                                        'authenticate' => array (
                                            'Form' => array (
                                                'fields' => array ('username' => 'email_address'),
                                                'scope' => array ('User.active' => 1)
                                            )
                                        ),
                                        'authorize' => array ('Controller'),
//                                        'unauthorizedRedirect' => '/' // when going to a page the user is not authorized to go to
                                    )
                                );
```

The commented out lines use the defaults, but they are included for reference to their default values. This is exactly the same in both applications. CPRACL is a plugin component that I am using instead of Cake's ACL component, but it fails long before it gets to any of that.

Also in **AppController.php**:

```
public function beforeFilter ()
{
    $login_user = $this->User->find ('first', array ('conditions' => array ('id' => $this->Auth->user ('id'))));
    if (!empty ($login_user))
        $this->set ('login_user', $login_user ['User']);
}

public function isAuthorized ($user = null)
{
    // This never gets called in the application that does not work, but it does get called in the one that works.
}
```

In both applications, it sets up the Auth component as defined in AppController.php, then it calls beforeFilter to check to see if the user is already logged in. This is a convenience so that when they get redirected to a different page, the application can display the username of the user who is logged in. It works fine and I don't think it is causing any problems.

The next thing that happens is it calls `UsersController::login()`

```
    public function login ()
    {
        $redirect_url = $this->Auth->redirectUrl ();
        if ($this->Auth->loggedIn ())
            return $this->redirect ($redirect_url);

//die (print_r ($this->request->data, true));
        if ($this->request->is ('post'))
        {
//die (Debugger::dump ($this->Auth));
            if ($this->Auth->login ())
                return $this->redirect ($redirect_url);
            else
                return $this->redirect ($this->Auth->loginAction);
        }
    }
```

I used the two commented out lines to compare what is happening between the two applications. The two applications get exactly the same data in the post. For the dump of the Auth object, here is what I get:

```
object(AuthComponent) {
    components => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Session',
        (int) 1 => 'RequestHandler'
    )
    authenticate => array(
        'Form' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
    authorize => array(
        (int) 0 => 'Controller'
    )
    ajaxLogin => null
    flash => array(
        'element' => 'default',
        'key' => 'auth',
        'params' => array([maximum depth reached])
    )
    loginAction => array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => null
    )
    loginRedirect => null
    logoutRedirect => array(
        'controller' => 'users',
        'action' => 'login',
        'plugin' => null
    )
    authError => 'You are not authorized to access that location.'
    unauthorizedRedirect => true
    allowedActions => array(
        (int) 0 => 'register',
        (int) 1 => 'login',
        (int) 2 => 'logout'
    )
    request => object(CakeRequest) {}
    response => object(CakeResponse) {}
    settings => array(
        'authenticate' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        ),
        'authorize' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
    Session => object(SessionComponent) {}
    [protected] _authenticateObjects => array()
    [protected] _authorizeObjects => array()
    [protected] _user => array()
    [protected] _methods => array(
        (int) 0 => 'index',
        (int) 1 => 'view',
        (int) 2 => 'add',
        (int) 3 => 'register',
        (int) 4 => 'login',
        (int) 5 => 'logout',
        (int) 6 => 'toggleactive',
        (int) 7 => 'changePassword',
        (int) 8 => 'passwordHash',
        (int) 10 => 'edit_pwd',
        (int) 11 => 'edit_your_pwd',
        (int) 12 => 'isAuthorized'
    )
    [protected] _Collection => object(ComponentCollection) {}
    [protected] _componentMap => array(
        'Session' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        ),
        'RequestHandler' => array(
            [maximum depth reached]
        )
    )
}
```

That is what both applications return from the Auth object dump when I send the login request. It says the user is not authorized to access that location, but I think that is because it hasn't actually logged the user in yet, so I don't think the dump of that Auth object is of much value, but I included it here anyway.

But here is the most important part because it is the only thing that is obviously different between the two applications. When I perform the login on the working application, it logs me in successfully and my layout (which displays the most recent query) shows this query. Notice the id field. The id field is correct in the query and it works.

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`user_id`, `User`.`email_address`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`active`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `brian_cake_test`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `id` = '529f9a8c-3460-46a2-a97c-6a6242a26b88' LIMIT 1
```

But when I do exactly the same thing for the application that does not work, everything happens exactly the same way except that it redirects me back to the login page, which it should do if it fails to login, and it displays this query in my layout.

```
SELECT `User`.`id`, `User`.`user_id`, `User`.`email_address`, `User`.`first_name`, `User`.`last_name`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`active`, `User`.`created`, `User`.`modified` FROM `brian_cake_test`.`users` AS `User` WHERE `id` IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

Notice how the id is NULL in the second query. I have no idea why this is happening.

My **User.php** model is just an empty class, exactly the same in both application, but one works perfectly and the other does not.

```
<?php
App::uses ('AppModel', 'Model');
class User extends AppModel
{
    public $name = 'User';
}
```

I have racked my brain trying to figure out what is different between these two applications, and I can't think of anything, and nothing I try will make it work. I don't want to post hundreds of lines of code when I know that 99% of it has nothing to do with this problem, but I have no idea why it works in one but not the other. I will gladly post more information if you think you might know what the problem is. Any help would be much appreciated. This is very important to me.

Answer (score 1):

Actually if its exactly the same code and DB it shouldn't be a reason not to work.

Have you tried clearing the cache folders? Those files sometimes mess up the app.

Comment: I did try clearing the cache, but it did not solve the problem and I never figured out why it wasn't working. There must be something configured wrong somewhere, or a conflict, and I never figured it out. I wound up copying the working application to a new directory and tediously moving all the functionality into it. It took me a whole day, but all the features seem to work now. Unfortunately, I have no information to offer about what was causing the problem.